# what is the better hosting for django?

Tags: hosting, django

I need to serve a Django App online, but, what is the best hosting for this Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoFriendlyWebHosts

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the Heroku-style variants for the Python world.

[Gondor](http://gondor.io/) and [Silver Lining](http://cloudsilverlining.org/) are just two of a new breed coming about.